# Far Cry 3: Bow Scope measuring

Tags: far-cry-3

So I have recently started running around with the bow equipped with the scope.  When I am zoomed in, the markers indicate which point is aiming at what distance.   I try to estimate the virtual distance and line up the corresponding marker in the scope but when I let go, the bolt falls embarrassingly short.   So my question is: Are the measurements in feet or meters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I recall, the measurements are in meters.

As for the measurements, here is a good thread for tips on shooting with the bow: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632849-far-cry-3/64795166

Here is an excerpt:

> Place the 0 marker on their head, if the 100 marker stops at their feet they are 25 meters away.
>
> Place the 50 marker on their head, if the 80 marker stops at their knee they are 50 meters away.
>
> Place the 0 marker on their head, if the 50 marker stops at their knee they are 80 meters away.
>
> Place the 0 marker on their head, if the 50 marker stops at their feet they are 100 meters away.

Comment: Thank you.    Admittedly that does sound a little complicated but I will give it a go.  When i try to reckon a distance to target in game,  I fail miserably.    Am I the only person to have these issues with the bow?    I feel if may be slapstick for me to start a new question solely based on that.

Comment: The estimation of the distance with the bow requires trial-and-error... No one is good at it the first time and it takes practice.

Comment: Thank you AV. After playing major stealthy assassin marksman type characters in oblivion and skyrim I had delusions of grandeur about using the bow in far cry but I have been brought back to earth in a rather unceremonious fashion. I have the bit between my teeth now.